# ¿Cómo puedo borrar una fila en específico según un numero dado?

Tags: vba

soy nuevo en VBA y estoy creando una base de datos en Excel, esta base de datos tiene una tabla donde se le agrega información, la tabla se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toda esta información se pasa a una tabla transpuesta hecha con la opción "Insertar Tabla" de Excel.

Esta base ya tiene macros hechas como agregar, para agregar información a una tabla, limpiar para eliminar el texto de las celdas de la primera tabla y demás. Un ejemplo:

```
 Sub AgregarIns()
'
' AgregarIns Macro
'

'
    Rows("18:18").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("C3:C9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("C10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J18").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K18").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M18").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I18").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@Valor]/[@Cantidad]"
    Range("I18").Select
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_-$ * #,##0.0_-;-$ * #,##0.0_-;_-$ * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_-$ * #,##0_-;-$ * #,##0_-;_-$ * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Range("L18").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@Valor]*[@[% Imp.]]"
    Range("L18").Select
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_-$ * #,##0.0_-;-$ * #,##0.0_-;_-$ * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_-$ * #,##0_-;-$ * #,##0_-;_-$ * ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INSUMOS").ListObjects("Tabla1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INSUMOS").ListObjects("Tabla1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add2 Key:=Range("Tabla1[[#All],[Número]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INSUMOS").ListObjects("Tabla1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("I18").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
    Range("L18").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
End Sub
```

Estas macros asignadas a botones fueron hechas por medio de la opción "Grabar macro".

Lo que deseo saber es como eliminar una fila en específico de la tabla insertada, es decir que al colocar un número y pulsar en un botón me elimine la fila según el numero que le indique:

```
*Número   Ej: 3    *Botón*  //Así como aparece en la imagen
```

De tal forma que si por ejemplo coloco 5, esta macro busque en la tabla donde esta el número 5 y elimina toda la fila.

Por ahora gracias a unos videos de YouTube tengo esto, lo cual me indica donde esta la fila del número que le indico pero no se como eliminarla

```
Sub Eliminar()

Dim HojaDatos As Worksheet
Dim Tabla As ListObject
Dim ValorEncontrado As Range
Dim Selected As Integer

Set HojaDatos = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INSUMOS")
Set Tabla = HojaDatos.ListObjects("Tabla1")

Selected = Range("F8").Value

Set ValorEncontrado = Tabla.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Find(Selected, LookAt:=xlWhole)


If Not ValorEncontrado Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Valor encontrado en la fila: " & ValorEncontrado.Row
Else
MsgBox "Valor no encontrado"
End If

End Sub
```

He intentado colocar este ValorEncontrado.Row abajo del Set ValorEncontrado, pero me arroja un error el cual me indica que el uso de la propiedad no es valido.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir, si no he entendido mal:

```
MsgBox "Valor encontrado en la fila: " & ValorEncontrado.Row
ValorEncontrado.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Si me sirvió, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada. Cierra la pregunta y puntúa la solución. Gracias